# C# Multi webbrowser private mode. Each webbrowser in one form

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have an app winform C#. I create multi form, and with each form, I've created one browser. But browser still share session with together. So how can I let each webbrowser in private mode. I try to create Background Worker and open form in backgroundWork but not success.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do what you are talking about with the WebBrowser control.  Try Awesomium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a WebBrowser you need to launch each in a separate process and then reparent them in your application.

Comment: You can explain more....Or could you put some code demo here plz. I need it Giang regorio

Comment: Hey Giangregorio! I try to open multi webbrowser in multi process! But it not success, could you help me

Comment: Not at the moment but i will post some code that can help you.

Comment: Where are you stuck at the moment? You reach to launch an external process? You are trying to reparent it in your app?

Comment: How can I reparent it. this is my code
You can give me skype to contact...plz

I reparent it like this: WB.Parent = this;

Comment: In my app! I want to login multi account in the sametime by multi webbrowser! This is my problem to do this app. I want to separate it's session to make login multi account! At least sample with facebook, google or some website

Comment: Providing a full working example is not easy and not fast. I can explain you what to do and then it's up to you to work on a full working solution, asking on specific problem.

Comment: You have to: 
1) create another app with only the webbrowser
2) launch the just created app from your main app
3) find the handle of the launched app and reparent it in your main app
4) find a way to communicate if needed between the two app (ipc?)

Comment: Thanks! But I dont understand step 3...Could you put some code in my answer comment. Plz

Comment: Ill' try to make a small test app today or tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm waiting you! Could you give me some info to contact...plz Giangregorio